# Linux search for file name with multiple paramter

Tags: linux, osx-lion

Imagine the below database that has thousands of files.  I want to search for a file name that has the letter D. and 0329.  I tried this but it searches all directory not current one and search does not work together.

```
find . -name "*D.*" | find . -name "*0329*"
```

File Names

```
A.20180329
A.20180327
B.20180329
B.20180321
C.20180321
D.20180329
D.20180329
D.20180327
D.20180321
E.20180321
E.20180321
```

Comment: So... You want to find files in the current directory that start with "D." and end with "0329"? Strikes me that there may be rather easier ways than with `find`, if that's really what you're asking, but it's hard to tell. Which of your list of files should match? (And is your question for Linux, or for OS X Lion, which is not a Linux variant?)

Answer (score -1):

Below command should work if its linux.

```
ls -lRt *|grep D|grep 0329
```